# How to fix it ? i am very very new to java

Tags: java

package app;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.UUID;

public class AccountThis {
    private static Scanner scanner;

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    //name input
    scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
       System.out.print( "Type your name: " );
        String nameInput = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Hello" + " " + nameInput);

        //deposit input 
            scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
               System.out.print( "Type how much you want to deposit:" );
                double depositInput = scanner.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("you want to deposit" + " " + depositInput + "$");


                    public AccountThis(String id) {


                        System.out.println("ID Generated"
                                + "Please Write it down :" + id);




                }


                    class RandomStringUUID {}
                    public id = randID;{

                        UUID randID = UUID.randomUUID();
                        UUID randomUUIDString = randID;
                        System.out.println(randomUUIDString );


                    new AccountThis( nameInput, depositInput, id);
                    }
                    {



                    }
            }




public AccountThis() {
    System.out.println( "created an account." );
}

public AccountThis( String nameInput ) {

    System.out.println( " created account with name " + nameInput );



}


public AccountThis(double depositInput) {

    System.out.println(depositInput + "$" + "added to your account!" );
}


}
```

i am new to  java and  i am trying to get id and assign it to the console with some text as you can see i failed a little bit if you can help me figure it out i would be very very happy

btw  i called it id cause i set on it all night and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: For a start each public class needs to be in a separate java file

Comment: *im new to java* - surely you are kidding us

Comment: you can't use inappropriate word like d*** . its a public platform. kindly remove this.

Comment: im sorry @KhalidShah

Comment: im not @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It is working fine

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.UUID;

public class AccountThis {

  private static Scanner scanner;


  public AccountThis(String nameInput) {

    System.out.println(" created account with name " + nameInput);
  }

  public AccountThis() {
    System.out.println("created an account.");
  }

  public AccountThis(double depositInput) {

    System.out.println(depositInput + "$" + "added to your account!");
  }

  public AccountThis(String nameInput, double depositInput, String id) {
    System.out.println(" created account with \n ID : " + id + ", \n name : " + nameInput);
    System.out.println(depositInput + "$" + "added to your account!");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //name input
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type your name: ");
    String nameInput = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hello" + " " + nameInput);

    //deposit input
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type how much you want to deposit:");
    double depositInput = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("you want to deposit" + " " + depositInput + "$");

    UUID randID = UUID.randomUUID();
    String id=randID.toString();

    new AccountThis(nameInput, depositInput,id);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but what im struggling with is assigning an id to the user and displaying it

Comment: Check again. Answer is updated . Hope it will helps.

Comment: @DavePeace is it helpful ?

Comment: yes man thank you. you helped me soo much.@Khalid Shah
what was the problem btw?
and if i want to store all the inputs at some kind of table what function sould i use?